# Substitute DISTINCT ON for query transformation (Postgresql to Redshift)

Tags: query, redshift, distinct, rank

I need to transform my Postgresql query to Redshift and I working with the following data, here is an excerpt:
[image]

In my final output, I would like only to keep rows with the highest rank (in green). And I was using the following query, which works to get the output, but I have to transform it into Redshift because the visualization tool is only using Redshift and Redshift doesn't recognize DISTINCT ON.

```
select distinct on customer_id
id_created,
customer_id,
call_start, 
status_prior,   
status_after,   
rank() over (partition by customer_id order by call_start) as rank
order by customer_id, rank desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my workaround, that works with Redshift:

select * from (select
id_created, customer_id, call_start, status_prior, status_after,
rank() over (partition by customer_id order by call_start desc) as rank
) t
where rank=1;

It seems to work, however, the processing time is longer, because of the subquery.

Comment: Longer compared to what?